# Append text to the file name using dos

Tags: file, batch-file, text

I am using the below command to print all the csv files in a directory. I would want to append text before the file name. My directory structure is as following.

```
Test
    SaleRegionEast
               SaleData.csv
    SaleRegionWest
              SaleData.csv
    Inventory
            InventoryDetails.csv
```

`dir /b "C:\Temp\Test\*.csv"`

My expected output is:

- File SaleData.csv is from SaleRegionEast directory
- File SaleData.csv is from SaleRegionWest directory
- File InventoryDetails.csv is from Inventory directory

Comment: you want to rename files with appending the directory name?

Comment: does `dir /s /b "C:\Temp\Test\*.csv"` fit your needs?

Comment: Well I am trying to append some text to the file name along with the name of directory. I am not trying to rename the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b/s *.csv') do @echo File %~nxi is from %~pi directory
```